# Gravitational force of a cylinder on a point mass

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-gravity

I've been dealing with a problem, that is depicted on the picture. I had to calculate the gravitational force exerted on a point mass m at coordinates (0,0,h) by a cylinder with radius R, height R and constant density ro0 as illustrated in the picture. Now I've calculated the force as presented, but what puzzles me now, is how I would calculate the limit of this force, when R->0. L'Hospital rule could only take me one step, and the expected solution is $F_g$ between two point bodies, which then means $F=GmM/{h^2}$. However, the $R^{-3}$ won't go away and is thus popping out the infinity.

All the answers are greatly appreciated.

Cheers!

[image: Attempted solution]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works!

You need to expand your square roots binomially to *third* order in $\left(\frac{R}{h}\right)$. The first and second order terms cancel (if you've been careful with your algebra) and your big square bracket boils down to $h \times \frac{1}{2} \frac{R^3}{h^3}$, which is just what you need to give the expected limit.

Comment: "to third order in $\frac{R}{h}$", right?

Comment: Indeed so. That is the case.

Comment: Meant to write "in $\frac{R}{h}$ ". Now corrected.